# get aggregate meatures from a subquery

Tags: sql, hive

Given "my_table":

```
id       other_columns
a        ...
a        ...
b        ...
b        ...
b        ...
```

I am trying to get mean, min, max of line count across different IDs. So as a Hive learner, I was trying this:

```
SELECT avg(line_count), min(line_count), max(line_count)
FROM (SELECT count(*) AS line_count FROM my_table GROUP BY id);
```

Could someone explain the associated error message of

```
"cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in subquery source"?
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving an alias to the subquery:

```
SELECT avg(s.line_count), min(s.line_count), max(s.line_count)
FROM (SELECT count(*) AS line_count 
     FROM my_table GROUP BY id) AS s;
```